# Can an email address contain international (non-english) characters?

Tags: email, internationalization, non-english

If it's possible, should I accept such emails from users and what problems to expect when I will be sending mails to such addresses?

Comment: It's sad that this question was asked again [about 8 months later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address), and the new question has lots more votes, yet ALL of the information there is more outdated than the information here. I wish I could give all the answers here +5 or something.

Answer (score 73):

Officially, per [RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532) - **Yes**.

For a quick explanation, check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Internationalization) on the subject.

Comment: Additionally check out [RFC 6531: SMTP Extension for Internationalized Email](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531) in addition to [RFC 5335: Internationalized Email Headers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5335) and also [Are international characters (e.g. umlaut characters) valid in the local part of email adresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121359/are-international-characters-e-g-umlaut-characters-valid-in-the-local-part-of)

Comment: Better yet check [RFC 6532](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6532) and more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31066998/2350426).

Comment: Definitely see @BinaryZebra's comment further below in this thread.  RFC-5335 is now obsolete.  Its successor, RFC-6532, is the current standard (no longer experimental).

Answer (score 29):

Update 2015: Use [RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532)

The experimental [5335](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335) has been Obsoleted by: [6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532) and
this later has been set to "Category: Standards Track",
making *it* the standard.

The [Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532#section-3.2) (Syntax Extensions to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)) has updated most text fields to
include (proper) UTF-8.

```
The following rules extend the ABNF syntax defined in [RFC5322] and
[RFC5234] in order to allow UTF-8 content.

VCHAR   =/  UTF8-non-ascii
ctext   =/  UTF8-non-ascii
atext   =/  UTF8-non-ascii
qtext   =/  UTF8-non-ascii
text    =/  UTF8-non-ascii
             ; note that this upgrades the body to UTF-8
dtext   =/  UTF8-non-ascii

The preceding changes mean that the following constructs now
allow UTF-8:
   1.  Unstructured text, used in header fields like
       "Subject:" or "Content-description:".
   2.  Any construct that uses atoms, including but not limited
       to the local parts of addresses and Message-IDs. This
       includes addresses in the "for" clauses of "Received:"
       header fields.
   3.  Quoted strings.
   4.  Domains.

Note that header field names are not on this list; these are still
restricted to ASCII.
```

Please note the **explicit** inclusion of Domains.
And the explicit exclusion of header *names*.

Also Note about [NFKC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Combining_and_precomposed_characters):

```
The UTF-8 NFKC normalization form SHOULD NOT be used because
it may lose information that is needed to correctly spell
some names in some unusual circumstances.
```

And [Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532#section-3) start:

```
Also note that messages in this format require the use of the
SMTPUTF8 extension [RFC6531] to be transferred via SMTP.
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that some mail clients (server-tools and / or desktop tools) don't support it and throw an 'invalid email' exception when you try to send a mail to an address which contains umlauts for example.

If you want full support, you could do the trick with converting the email-address parts to  "punycode". This allows users to type in their addresses the usual way but you save it the supported-level way.

Example: müller.com » xn--mller-kva.com

Both points to the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

I would assume yes since a number of top level domains already allow non ascii
characters for domains and since the domain is part of an email address, it's
perfectly possible. An example for such a domain would be www.öko.de

Answer (score 2):

short answer: yes

not only in the username but also in the domain name are allowed.

Comment: Do you know which mail exchanger/domains already allow umlauts in local part of the email address?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. The IEEE plans to do this:
[H-Online article: IEFT planning internationalised email addresses](https://web.archive.org/web/20090302031911/http://www.h-online.com/news/IEFT-planning-internationalised-email-addresses--/111542), here is the [RfC: SMTP Extension for Internationalized Email Addresses](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5336.txt)

Quote from H-Online (as it went down):

> The Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) has published three crucial documents for the standardisation of email address headers
>   that include symbols outside the ASCII character set. This means that
>   soon you'll be able to use Chinese characters, French accents, and
>   German umlauts in email addresses as well as just in the body of the
>   message. So if your name is Zoë and you work for a company that makes
>   façades, you might be interested in a new email address. But
>   representatives of providers are already moaning. They say there would
>   need to be an "upgrade mania" if the Unicode standard UTF-8 is to
>   replace the American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII)
>   currently used as the general email language.
>
> RFC 5335 specifies the use of UTF-8 in practically all email headers.
>   Changes would have to be made to SMTP clients, SMTP servers, mail user
>   agents (MUAs), software for mailing lists, gateways to other media,
>   and everywhere else where email is processed or passed along. RFC 5336
>   expands the SMTP email transport protocol. At the level of the
>   protocol, the expansion is labelled UTF8SMTP.
>
> A new header field will be added as a sort of "emergency parachute" to
>   ensure that UTF-8 emails have a soft landing if they are thrown out
>   before reaching the recipient by systems that have not been upgraded.
>   The "OldAddress" is a purely ASCII address. But OldAddress is not to
>   be used as a channel for a second transfer attempt, but rather to make
>   sure that feedback is sent home.
>
> Finally, RFC5337 ensures that correct messages are sent pertaining to
>   the delivery status of non-ASCII emails. The correct address of an
>   unreachable addressee must be sent back, even if further transport has
>   been refused. The email Address Internationalization (EAI) working
>   group is also working on a number of "downgrade mechanisms" for
>   various header fields and the envelope. If possible, original header
>   information is to be "packaged" and preserved.
>
> Germany's DeNIC, the registrar for the ".de" domain, is nonetheless
>   taking this in its stride. "There is really not much we can do",
>   explained DeNIC spokesperson Klaus Herzig. DeNIC is instead paying
>   more attention to the update that the IETF is working on for the
>   standard of international domains – RFC3490, or IDNA2003 as it's
>   sometimes known. "We are not that happy about it because there is no
>   backwards compatibility," Herzig explained. When the update comes,
>   DeNIC says it will be throwing its weight behind the symbol "ß" - also
>   known as estzett - which has been overlooked up to now. The German
>   registrar also says that it may wait a bit before switching in light
>   of the lack of backward compatibility. Once the new standard is
>   running stably and registrars and providers have adopted it, the ß
>   will be added.
>
> In contrast, experts believe that Chinese registrars in China and
>   Taiwan will quickly implement the change for internationalised email.
>   Representatives of CNIC and TWNIC are authors of the standards.
>   Chinese users currently have to write emails in ASCII to the left of
>   the @ and in Chinese characters to the right of it for Chinese
>   domains, which have already been internationalized.
>
> (Monika Ermert)

Comment: This link is dead now as the "The H" shut down?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, but they need to be encoded specially.

[Look at this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_e-mail). Read the part that refers to email-headers and RFC 2047.

Comment: Do you know which mail exchanger/domains already allow umlauts in local part of the email address?