# Validating the email address in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, email-validation

I am trying to put validation in text field containing email address.
What is to be added in string "emailRegEx" to limit the user from inserting three dots in email address or what I have to write in method for same.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string.
```

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)EmailValidationL:(NSString *)email
{
    NSString *emailRegEx =@"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
    @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
    @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
    @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
    @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
    @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
    @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

    NSPredicate *regExPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
    a= [regExPredicate evaluateWithObject:email];
    return a;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for validating email address in Objective-C on iOS 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c-on-ios-2-0)

Comment: @zpasternack: i want to validate dynamically , that user should not enter 3rd dot.if it enters then replace it by null string.Above method is validating in ShouldEndEditing-method

Comment: Now that we have UTF-8 domain names, how does this change these regular expressions? e.g. camtasia教程网.com

Comment: Many of the answers here will prevent valid email addresses from being accepted. There are now many top level domains longer than four characters (see list at [https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt]) and millions of users with email accounts on those domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by using the extension of String

```
extension String {
  var isEmail: Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
  }
}
```

now you can use it as

```
if emailtext.isEmail {  
  print("email is valid")    
} else {
  print("email is not valid") 
}
```

Answer (score 18):

There are better [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428376/1207152) to validate an email address.

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Comment: i want to validate dynamically , that user should not enter 3rd dot.if it enters then replace it by null string, Above method is validating in ShouldEndEditing-method

Answer (score 8):

```
NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];

if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:yourtextFieldName.text] == NO) 
{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"enter the Valid Mail id" message:@"Please Enter Valid Email Address." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

**Swift**

```
 var emailReg: String = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
var emailTest: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg)

if emailTest.evaluateWithObject(yourtextFieldName.text!) == false {
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "enter the Valid Mail id", message: "Please Enter Valid Email Address.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "okay", otherButtonTitles: "")
alert.show()
}
```

**Swift3**

```
let emailReg = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg)
if emailTest.evaluate(withObject: yourtextFieldName.text) == false {
 UIAlertView(title: "enter the Valid Mail id", message: "Please Enter Valid Email Address.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "okay", otherButtonTitles: "").show()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

This regex will limit the user from inserting three dots in email address (or any number of consecutive dots), such as

```
username@example...com
```

Another rule with dot is the username and domain must not begin or end with dot, such as

```
.username.@.example.com
```

Many regexes in the internet allow invalid email addresses. Before adopting one, you might want to try testing it with some invalid email addresses, to see if they get rejected. You can use the two examples I mention here as a start.

```
- (BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString *)email
{
    NSString *regex1 = @"\\A[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.)+[a-z]{2,4}\\z";
    NSString *regex2 = @"^(?=.{1,64}@.{4,64}$)(?=.{6,100}$).*";
    NSPredicate *test1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex1];
    NSPredicate *test2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex2];
    return [test1 evaluateWithObject:email] && [test2 evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

See [validate email address using regular expression in Objective-C](http://seaf-email.blogspot.com/p/code.html#objectivec).

Comment: Thanks for this, your `regex1` test saved me a lot of hassle by limiting multiple dots. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

iOS already has built-in data detectors for a number of different data types. Although email isn't one of those types, an email address falls under the subtype of a link. Knowing that, it's easy to check for an email address:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = 
   [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

NSString *string = @"johndoe@gmail.com";
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:string
                           options:kNilOptions
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, 
                                     NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) 
{
  if([result.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"mailto:"].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    NSLog(@"Match: %@", result);
  }
}];
```

Matt Thompson's NSHipster blog has an [excellent article](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) on `NSDataDetector` and its useage.

Answer (score 0):

building on [memmons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257550/memmons)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547226), the following code should validate an entire email string assuming we can trust `NSDataDetector`

```
- (BOOL)isPlausibleEmailAddress
{   
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector =
    [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

    NSRange matchRange = [detector rangeOfFirstMatchInString:self options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];

    return matchRange.length == [self length];
}
```