# How can I check that email address has been entered perfeclty in UITextfiled

Tags: iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email validation on textField in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428304/email-validation-on-textfield-in-iphone-sdk)

I have an app in which I want to get the user's email address as input. I want to check that the user has entered email address properly; like @ should be in the text in the field. How can I do this?

```
textField.text=@"ali@hotmail.com"
```

If the text box has this value then OK otherwise it should alert that email address should be correct

Comment: SO is not personal serach assistant, you need to google before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx]; 
    if  ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:m_CtrlTxtFld_Email.text] != YES && [m_CtrlTxtFld_Email.text length]!=0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter valid email address" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use regExp validation, like this function

```
-(BOOL) isValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
    checkString = [checkString lowercaseString];
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";

    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

use it like this

```
if([self isValidEmail:textField.text])
   //Valid
else
   //Not valid, do the alert
```

Comment: This worked for me until new domain extensions came into effect ... How can an email address be checked now?!

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method :-

```
- (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *) candidate 
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

The method will return `TRUE` if input is in correct format otherwise `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)isValidEmaill:(NSString*)in_EmailId
{
    if( (0 != [in_EmailId rangeOfString:@"@"].length) &&  (0 != [in_EmailId rangeOfString:@"."].length) )  
    {  
        NSMutableCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]mutableCopy]autorelease];  
        [invalidCharSet removeCharactersInString:@"_-"];  

        NSRange range1 = [in_EmailId rangeOfString:@"@" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];  

        // If username part contains any character other than "."  "_" "-"  
        NSString *usernamePart = [in_EmailId substringToIndex:range1.location];  
        NSArray *stringsArray1 = [usernamePart componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];  
        for (NSString *string in stringsArray1) {  
            NSRange rangeOfInavlidChars=[string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: invalidCharSet];  
            if(rangeOfInavlidChars.length !=0 || [string isEqualToString:@""])  
                return NO;  
        }  

        NSString *domainPart = [in_EmailId substringFromIndex:range1.location+1];  
        NSArray *stringsArray2 = [domainPart componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];  

        for (NSString *string in stringsArray2) {  
            NSRange rangeOfInavlidChars=[string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidCharSet];  

            if(rangeOfInavlidChars.length !=0 || [string isEqualToString:@""])  

                return NO;  
        }  

        return YES;  
    }  
    else // no '@' or '.' present  
    {
        //[mEmailAddrTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO; 
    }
}
```