# Email Validation in iOS

Tags: ios, validation, email, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

Email validation checking in iPhone programming can be done using RegexKitLite library (iOS2.0), `NSPredicate` (iOS 3.0 onwards) and `NSRegularExpression` (iOS 4.0). But can anybody state what is the advantage of one over the other and which is the best validating option of the three stated.

Comment: FYI, it's an example of something incredibly easier on Android, it's builtin there .. if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(someString).matches())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it largely depends on the minimum version of iOS an App will support, and if there's a built-in class that'll do the job, use it. As you hinted, you'd use some other 3rd-party framework to support older versions in a consistent way.

Right now, I'd use `NSPredicate` or `NSRegularExpression`, both are supported from iOS 4 onwards, which is quite likely to be the minimum supported version for new iOS Apps, if not iOS 5.

Useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139619/check-that-an-email-address-is-valid-on-ios).

Comment: Thank you for giving solution particular to the question only. Right now i am working on iOS 5.0 and NSPredicate is working fine on it.

Answer (score 11):

i am using NSPredicate always...and it is working fine

```
NSString *emailid = emailField.text;
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
BOOL myStringMatchesRegEx=[emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailid];
```

Comment: how to restrict the user to enter his email id as only @gmail.com in text field.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is a refactored one from [the excellent solution provided in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638271/1436634)..

```
///Returns YES (true) if EMail is valid
+(BOOL) IsValidEmail:(NSString *)emailString Strict:(BOOL)strictFilter
{
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";

    NSString *emailRegex = strictFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)emailStr
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailStr];
}

On Button Click :

if (![self validateEmail:[txtEmail text]])
    {
        alertValidator.message = @"Please Enter Valid Email Address !";
        [alertValidator show];
        txtEmail.text = @"";
        [txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option, hands down, is [Mailgun's free email validation API](http://blog.mailgun.com/post/free-email-validation-api-for-web-forms/). I've written a simple objective-C wrapper for it:

https://github.com/benzguo/BZGMailgunEmailValidation

```
BZGMailgunEmailValidator *validator = 
    [BZGMailgunEmailValidator validatorWithPublicKey:YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY];

[validator validateEmailAddress:self.emailFieldCell.textField.text
                        success:^(BOOL isValid, NSString *didYouMean) {
                        // Validation succeeded
                      } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                        // Validation failed
                      }];
```

If there's a connection error, the validator falls back to regex-based validation.

If you still want to validate emails using a regular expression, check out:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List

Answer (score 0):

complete email validation. try this

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)checkString
{

    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", laxString];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

how to create email id and password validation in ios

Hurry up, Easy for simple Validation of Email id check that after code useful.

```
- (IBAction)actLogin:(id)sender

{

    if([self validateEmailWithString:userNameText.text]==YES)
    {
         NSLog(@"valid email");
         if (passWordText.text.length>6)
         {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:userNameText.text forKey:@"username"];
            [defaults setObject:passWordText.text forKey:@"password"];
            [defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"islogin"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Login is Successfully !!");
         }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"invalid email and password");
    }
}
```

so,I Hope for helpful you.
 Thanks...