# Trying to validate email in iOS, crashing not sure why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation

I am using the code provided here for the validation [Check that an email address is valid on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139619/check-that-an-email-address-is-valid-on-ios) and in this SO answer I am just calling the method like so

```
-(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Then within my code like so:

```
NSString *emailCheck = self.txtEmail.text;
  //prints boolean statement
            NSLog([self NSStringIsValidEmail:emailCheck] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
            //validate email
            if([self NSStringIsValidEmail:emailCheck]) {
                [self alertStatus:@"Please enter a valid email" :@"Register Failed!" :0];
                //enables button on login error
                [btnRegister setEnabled:YES];
                [self callProgressBar:NO];
            }
```

I added the NSLog to see if I can get an output but it now crashes on the NSLog with a light blue lldb error only. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `NSStringIsValidEmail` return

Comment: I added the method above, it returns a Boolean

Comment: Does it fail on all values of self.txtEmail.text?

Comment: which line is giving the error, and could you include a stack trace / error message? It would greatly help

Comment: It fails on this line [self NSStringIsValidEmail:emailCheck]  nothing else, email check comes back as the string correctly... not sure how to get a stacktrace as the error is just (lldb) in light blue, self points correctly to the controller I am on as well.

Comment: I just tested the code with no issues. You don't have a break point set do you? That can cause a lldb in light blue?

Comment: PCoder123 wow I cannot believe I did not notice that, thanks if you want to write that up ill mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a blue lldb message without an error message can indicate that a breakpoint was set. You might want to check to see that all your breakpoints have been removed.