# Crash using NSPredicate in swift after Xcode Beta 6

Tags: ios, crash, swift, nspredicate, xcode6-beta6

My code worked good in Xcode beta 5 but after downloaded the beta 6, it crash.

This is the code I have :

```
extension String {

    /**
    * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139619/check-that-an-email-address-is-valid-on-ios
    */
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegex = ".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",emailRegex);
        return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(self);
    }
}
```

When executing, it crash at the NSPredicate line :

```
let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",emailRegex);
```

Someone know something about this problem ?

Comment: Your code seems to work without problems for me. Which input string did you test it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete derived data and then rebuild, this method fixed my problem !

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: Yes , just try it , There will be no harm , I promise

Comment: Glad it worked . I  think , since its new version of the beta, a lot of things changed  and different from beta 5 , if want to know whats new in beta6 , read the beta6 release not from developer site.

Comment: The derived data contains compiled (and precompiled) files.  Apparently there are some compatibility issues between beta 5 and beta 6.  There's a whole slew of symptoms that this can fix.