# there any way to make a text field entry email in xcode7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, xcode7

I want to make a user login form and it needs to use emails  Is there any way i can make a alert  if it is not an email? btw All of this is in xcode7 and swift2

Comment: You want email validation ?

Comment: Check email validation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139619/check-that-an-email-address-is-valid-on-ios