# Strange input value when it contains "nl@"

Tags: javascript, html, input

I found a strange behavior with the value of an input element (`e.target.value`) when it contains "nl@". All german umlauts after that will be transformed to something strange.

Examples:

```
nl@ü => nl@xn--tda
aanlaaa@u => aanlaaa@xn--tda
ünl@ü => ünl@ü
nl@dksdü => nl@xn--dksd-3ra
```

I prepared a litle codepen where you can tests it yourself and also explained the quirks a little bit more.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/christoph-fricke/pen/YOLXKR)

Does someone have an idea why this behavior occurs?

Comment: Could only reproduce on chrome, doesn't happen on firefox.

Comment: Any character before the `@` sign appears to cause this. I suggest you file a bug to Chromium

Comment: High I've found this thread which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121359/are-international-characters-e-g-umlaut-characters-valid-in-the-local-part-of