# Black diamonds for UTF8 symbols in the sender name when sending with sendmail

Tags: matlab

I tried to expand the 'from' field of my email, the code looks something like this:

```
name = 'Hans Müller';
mail = strcat(name, '<h.mueller@test.org>');
setpref('Internet','E_mail',mail);    
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','mail');
sendmail('input@test.org','New post',body);
```

That actually worked really well, but instead of the umlauts in the name of sender can see in outlook a black diamond - "M�ller" .
I tried to change the default charset with

```
setpref ('Internet', 'E_mail_Charset', 'utf-8')
```

and

```
setpref ('Internet', 'E_mail_Charset', 'iso-8859-1')
```

Both variants were unsuccessful, the charset 'iso-8859-1' spoiled the umlauts in the body, which used to look normal.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem? As I said, the body HTML text is absolutely fine, only the name of sender is not displayed correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a Outlook problem? MATLAB seems to handle the umlaut well.

Comment: I think that the settings in outlook are OK - under incoming emails are the senders with umlaut in their names and they are displayed correctly.

Comment: The From address in email is encoded in the email headers, not the email body, and I think email headers only support ASCII or Latin-1 values. There's probably some special encoding mechanism for it, and Matlab probably isn't aware of it, so your unicode "ü" is probably getting busticated when being transformed to an ASCII email header. I'll look in to this if I have time. Also, this is worthy of opening a ticket with Matlab Tech Support at support@mathworks.com.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760150/can-an-email-address-contain-international-non-english-characters and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6532. Matlab probably isn't on top of these things, because that's not their style.

Comment: BTW, you mean "Unicode", not "UTF8" here – Matlab stores its strings internally in UTF-16, not UTF-8, and transcoding has to happen when it converts its UTF-16 data to email headers or body text.

Answer (score 0):

I found an absolutely not elegant solution, and that is

```
regexprep(name,{'Ä','Ö','Ü','ä','ö','ü','ß'},{'Ã„','Ã–','Ãœ','Ã¤','Ã¶','Ã¼','ÃŸ'})
```

That solved my problem.